# getting other values from other classes revert to null or 1

Tags: java, android

When ever I want to get a value from another class say I need a value from `Bread.java`, telling me whether I have eaten bread `EatenBread` or not and how many slices of bread `SlicesEaten` I have eaten. and I need that value in `Info.java`

I would call to the other class by using this method:`

```
Bread bread = new Bread();
```

and then would get the value by doing this:

```
private boolean EatenBread = bread.EatenBread();
private int SlicesEaten = bread.SlicesEaten();
```

or

```
public boolean EatenBread = bread.EatenBread();
public int SlicesEaten = bread.SlicesEaten();
```

but `EatenBread` would instead of having the value of `true` it has the value of `null or false`

and `SlicesEaten` would instead of having the amount of slices eaten would have the value of `0` instead of the amount.

Now I have concluded that this seems to happen only after I have gotten the values over to say `Info.java` from `Bread.java` the values are the ones desired when they are first in `Bread.java` but once they have been called to `Info.java` they obtain the undesired values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the return statements within the Bread.java be off? Is the info.java your main class? I tested your code and I was able to get the proper values but if you provide the code for the other methods it may help pinpoint your problem.

Also Im not sure of the entire context of your application but utilizing getters and setters is a good practice =). If you are unfamiliar with them, you may want to check them out since they are pretty handy! 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Hope this helped in some way.

Comment: I looked at the link you sent me to, and it sent me to Java EE 6 tutorial on getters and setters. but i am working with an android application here. is there a difference?

Comment: Getters and setters are the same across the playing field. You can name them anything you want(if you dont want to go with naming conventions) but the concept is the same.

Comment: what is the purpose of getters and setters? im not sure of what they do necessarily

Comment: They allow you to utilize encapsulation within your application. Its a very valuable skill to use within your programming. This video describes them and their purpose in detail. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wF18uVxjtvc